Как задать min-height: calc с переменной через js?
Как задать min-height: calc с переменной через js? Сейчас minHeight не срабатывает. Спасибо!
    let body = document.querySelector('.main-home__content');
let titles = document.querySelectorAll('.main-home__titles');
let mainHome = document.querySelector('.page__main-home');

function start() {
    titles.forEach(title => {
        let hBody = window.getComputedStyle(body, false).height;
        hBody = Number(hBody.slice(0, hBody.length - 2));

        let hTitle = window.getComputedStyle(title, false).height;
        hTitle = Number(hTitle.slice(0, hTitle.length - 2));


        let minHeightBody = hTitle + 'px';

        mainHome.style.minHeight = "calc(100vh + `${minHeightBody}`)";
        title.style.bottom = hBody + 'px';
    });

}

